# Query child records when relationship is with same object

Tags: apex, trigger, adderror, child-to-parent

I have a lookup field on case which points to case object. (Field: Parent__c). I want to query child case records from a parent case using an aggregate query. Below is the query I have used-

```
[SELECT Id, (SELECT Id,parent__c FROM Cases) FROM Case WHERE Id IN:SetIds ]
```

However, this query is not returning anything in 'Cases' in spite of 'Child Relationship Name' for the field being 'Cases'.
I know I am definitely missing something here. Hence request someone to please help me towards implementing my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cases relationship uses the built in ParentId field. Since you're using a custom lookup field, you need to use the custom relationship name, likely Cases__r.

Answer (score 0):

- First Go to the Case Object and then Open Your Parent__c field.
- Now you got the Relationship Name here.
- Then follow below Query :

  SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, parent__c FROM RelationshipName__r) FROM Case WHERE Id IN:SetIds

NOTE : If you are Using Custom Lookup Field for relationship Query, You must append the "__c" at the last of RelationshipName.
And If you are using Standard Lookup Field for Relationship Query then there is no need to use "__r".